# Easy quick way or tool to selectively pull Snapshots / Frames from a Video and put it into a Comic Strip type structure?

Tags: video-editor, keyframes, screenshot

Easy quick way or tool to selectively pull Snapshots from a Video and put it into a Comic Strip type structure?

Take a minute long mp4 video and pull specific snapshots into a set of comic strip type of frames / story board type of layout.

Additionally, add some annotation text to frames if & when needed; manually or from the subtitles (embedded, inbuilt or external - .srt / .sub/ .txt)

Simple way / tool/ steps to do this?

PS: I am aware that Major / Big Video & Photo shop type programs will have/ allow way more than this. I am looking/ hoping to do this in a quick light way - maybe repeatedly for some videos.

If more context helps, I am trying to comic strip frames some stand up brief comedy routines' setup to punch-liners into static frames.

I wonder if such features can help?

[Good app / process for organizing video snapshots into a storyboard?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17620/good-app-process-for-organizing-video-snapshots-into-a-storyboard)

Comment: This is not really a question about video production. For multiple screenshots you might use ffmpeg (parameters: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) but for a tool that turns those into a comic strip you might get an answer on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ more quickly.

Comment: @Matt - Its more 1. selective Video Frame & 2. Subtitle extraction than it is just plain 
Screenshot taking. GD folks would probably flag and send me back saying its a video thing. Its more Storyboard / Video / Motion pictures than it is static Graphic Design.